# How to initialize a string or char jagged array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

Besides using a loop.  An int array can be initialized with 0s easy like `arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => new int[100]).ToArray();`.

Is there a way I can initialize a string or char array in a similar fashion?

Comment: Plug `string` or `char` into your expression where you have `int`. What did you get? Is it what you want?

Comment: What's the result you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to initialize it with string 0s but instead I get a bunch of nulls when I write to the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
string[] arrayOfStringZeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                        .Select(i => "0")
                                        .ToArray();


char[] arrayOfCharZeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                   .Select(i => '0')
                                   .ToArray();
```

**Updated**

```
char[][] jaggedOfCharZeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                       .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                                              .Select(j => '0')
                                                              .ToArray())
                                       .ToArray();
```

Actually it would probably be slightly more efficient to do:

```
char[] initZeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                             .Select(i => '0')
                             .ToArray();


char[][] jaggedOfCharZeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                       .Select(i => (char[])initZeros.Clone())
                                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: But how would I do that for a jagged array?

Comment: Ok that works, I see how it's done.  Thanks.  But the inner i should be a j or something or it'll conflict.

Comment: I added a slightly better version.

Comment: Beware, the second, "better", version adds a reference to the same char array to each first dimension index of the 2D array, insread of a new instance.